# Different results for Magnetic field using different methods

Tags: electromagnetism

[image: http://www.ux1.eiu.edu/~cfadd/1360/30MagSrcs/Images/FigP30.08.jpg]

In calculating the magnetic field created by this current at the center point of the loop using [Biot-Savart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biot%E2%80%93Savart_law) and using the vector potential will there be a difference? If so what is it and why?

Using Biot-Savart the Magnetic field is simply a superposition of fields created by straight wire and loop. But how does one calculate the vector potential at the center?

Comment: Have you tried it and gotten a difference? If so, it would help if you summarize or show your calculations.

Answer (score 3):

The vector potential at point $x$ can be calculated as the integral over the wire of the vector current divided by the distance to $x$.  Take the curl of the resulting expression, move the curl inside the integral sign, do a few manipulations and wala!, you've got the Biot-Savart law!  They are exactly the same.

Comment: I haven't been able to set up the integral to calculate the vector potential that doesn't diverge. And what do you mean move the curl inside the integral?

Comment: I see what's bothering you, the 1/r divergence.  That disappears when you differentiate under the integral sign.  $\partial_{x} \int dy A(x,y) = \int dy \partial_{x} A(x,y)$. A mathematician might take offense.

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Would you recommend do the integration in polar coordinates or just Cartesian?

Comment: A is only a function of x when it comes to the infinite, straight wire.

Comment: I know, I was just trying to show what I mean by differentiating under the integral sign.  Why don't you calculate the vector potential for the ring separately (it won't diverge).